# Force MVC site to use live database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I've been working on my MVC application for a while now, using the code-first database method.

Now, I've setup a SQL Server 2008 database, and was hoping to use that for the production use.

But, no matter what, it still uses the locally-made `.sdf` database.

I've tried editing the `web.config` `connectionStrings` to

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlServer" 
        connectionString="Server=-edit-;Database=-edit-;User Id=-edit-;Password=-edit-;" />
   <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SignalR-20130806111535;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SignalR-20130806111535.mdf" />-->
</connectionStrings>
```

Which doesn't work at all, although it seems as if

```
<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
   </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Has something to do with it.

I've tried checking for tutorials, but am failing at every stop.

Comment: Are you sure that you changed the rights web.config. There's the Debug and Release. You should change the main web.config. Theres the View web.config as well, You must change the main project one

Comment: Yeah, I made sure to change the right one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to verify the correct name you have to assign to the Connection string, it takes the complete class name, for example, if you have a DbContext like this:

```
namespace ApplicationOrders.EF
{
 public class OrderContext : DbContext
   {
       public OrderContext(){}
 }
}
```

the connection would be:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationOrders.EF.OrderContext"
```

Or you can add the Connection string name to the DbContext in this way:

```
public class OrderContext : DbContext
{
    public OrderContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {}
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much :D Its not everyday that an answer gets solved as easily as this.

Answer (score 0):

Note the provider class name should be

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

not

```
providerName="System.Data.SQlServer"
```